# Does the Deduction Theorem work for assertions of non-derivability?

Tags: logic

By the deduction theorem, if  $Γ,A⊢B$,  then  $Γ⊢A→B$ .

But may I also conclude that if $$Γ,A⊬B,$$  then  $$Γ⊬A→B \;?$$

Comment: Sure. Proof by contrapositive. If $\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$, then by monotonicity $\Gamma, A \vdash A \rightarrow B$, and by closure under the inference rules you can conclude $\Gamma, A \vdash B$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The deduction theorem is actually a biimplication: $$\Gamma, A \vdash B \iff \Gamma \vdash A \to B$$ The non-derivability biimplication then straightforwardly follows as the contraposition of each of the directions: $$\Gamma \not \vdash A \to B \iff \Gamma, A \not \vdash B$$

Answer (score 0):

$$Γ,A⊬B\\
\lnot ((Γ\land A)\to B)\\
(Γ\land A)\land\lnot B\\
Γ\land (A \land\lnot B)\\
Γ\land \lnot(\lnot A \lor B)\\
Γ\land \lnot(A \to B)\\
\lnot(Γ\to (A \to B))\\
 Γ⊬A→B$$